# Swift REPL mode random crash with reflect

Tags: swift, reflection, crash, closures, read-eval-print-loop

After learning about `reflect()` to learn types dynamically, I started using it and getting this curious crash:

```
# swift -version
Swift version 1.1 (swift-600.0.56.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0
# swift
Welcome to Swift!  Type :help for assistance.
1> println(reflect({1}))
Swift._OpaqueMirror
2> reflect({1})
Segmentation fault: 11
```

HOWEVER:

```
1> reflect({1}).dynamicType
$R0: MirrorType.Type = Swift._OpaqueMirror
```

This behavior is repeatable and the hardware / OS (10.10.2) is otherwise operating well. There's also a noticeable pause during evaluation as if a stack or buffer is overflowing. Variations such as using a variable assigned to the closure and reflecting on the variable also crash. Finally: running swift within lldb makes it work with proper output!!

```
[...]
(lldb) c
Process 3322 resuming
Welcome to Swift!  Type :help for assistance.
1> reflect({"a"})
reflect({"a"})
$R0: _OpaqueMirror = {
  data = {
    owner = {}
    ptr = {}
    metadata = 0x07fad7e8ffffff40
  }
}
```

Any insights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this was fixed in the Swift 1.2 beta:

```
% swift -v
Apple Swift version 1.2 (swiftlang-602.0.37.3 clang-602.0.37)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0
Welcome to Swift version 1.2. Type :help for assistance.
  1> println(reflect({1}))
Swift._OpaqueMirror
  2> reflect({1})
$R0: _OpaqueMirror = {
  data = {
    owner = {}
    ptr = {}
    metadata = 0x0000000100700068
  }
}
  3>
```